# How To Gather the Data In Angular Received From WebApi

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I'm new in programming specially in angular and I'd appreciate it if someone help me with my code, please.

A brief explanation of what I'm trying to do as a practice is:

Getting images from the web api in angular project.

- ASP.NET Framework Web API 4.7
- Angular CLI: 13.3.7
- Angular: 13.3.11

***Web API side:***

**Controller:**

```
   [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class HomeController : ApiController
    {
        private NavEcommerceDBfirstEntities db = new NavEcommerceDBfirstEntities();
        public HomeModel Get()
        {
            var streetBikes = db.Motorcycles
                .Where(m => m.Category.MotoCategory == "Street")
                .Select(m => new MotorcycleImgDTO
                {
                    Image = m.Image
                });
            var sportBikes = db.Motorcycles
                .Where(m => m.Category.MotoCategory == "Sport")
                .Select(m => new MotorcycleImgDTO
                {
                    Image = m.Image
                });
            var adventureBikes = db.Motorcycles
                .Where(m => m.Category.MotoCategory == "Adventure")
                .Select(m => new MotorcycleImgDTO
                {
                    Image = m.Image
                });
            var scooterBikes = db.Motorcycles
                .Where(m => m.Category.MotoCategory == "Scooter")
                .Select(m => new MotorcycleImgDTO
                {
                    Image = m.Image
                });
            var homeModel = new HomeModel
            {
                SportBikes = sportBikes,
                StreetBikes = streetBikes,
                AdventureBikes = adventureBikes,
                ScooterBikes = scooterBikes
            };

            return homeModel;
        }

    }
```

**Models:**

*HomeModel class:*

```
    public class HomeModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<MotorcycleImgDTO> StreetBikes { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<MotorcycleImgDTO> SportBikes { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<MotorcycleImgDTO> AdventureBikes { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<MotorcycleImgDTO> ScooterBikes { get; set; }

    }
```

*Motorcycle class:*

```
//Database First Approach and Created by ADO.NET 
    public partial class Motorcycle
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Motorcycle()
        {
            this.Carts = new HashSet<Cart>();
            this.OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
            this.Dealers = new HashSet<Dealer>();
        }
    
        public int MotorcycleId { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> BrandId { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CategoryId { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Dealer> Dealers { get; set; }
    }
```

**DTO class:**

```
    public class MotorcycleImgDTO
    {
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    }
```

***Angular Side:***

**Model:**

*home-categorised-bikes.model.ts:*

```
export interface FromDTOImgs{
    image: Byte[];
}

export interface HomeModel{
SportBikes: FromDTOImgs[];
StreetBikes: FromDTOImgs[]; 
AdventureBikes: FromDTOImgs[];
ScooterBikes: FromDTOImgs[];
}
```

**Service:**

*home-categorised-bikes.service.ts:*

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HomeCategorisedBikesService {

  imageUrl = 'https://localhost:44377/api/Home';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getImg(): Observable<BikesImg[]> {
    return this.http.get<BikesImg[]>(this.imageUrl);
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeCategorisedBikesService } from './services/home-categorised-bikes.service';
import{HomeModel} from './models/home-categorised-bikes.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'angular-UI';

  constructor(private homeCategorisedBikesService: HomeCategorisedBikesService){}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getAllBikesImgs();
}

getAllBikesImgs(){
this.homeCategorisedBikesService.getImg().subscribe(
  Response => {
    this.onHomeBikesImgsResponse(Response);
    console.log(Response);
  }  
)
}
public bikesImgs: string[] = [];
private onHomeBikesImgsResponse(Response: HomeModel[]): void {
Response.forEach((bikeImg: HomeModel) => {
  this.bikesImgs.push(`data:image/png;base64,${bikeImg.SportBikes}`);
});
}
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <h4>{{title}}</h4>

    <div *ngFor="let bikeImg of bikesImgs">
        <img [src]="bikeImg">
    </div>
```

***Swagger:***

[image: Swagger response]

***Question:***

Currently I'm getting an error in angular.

How to fix the angular side to get the images to be able to display them into the browser ?

***Error:***

*(parameter) Response: FromDTOImgs[]
Argument of type 'FromDTOImgs[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HomeModel[]'.
Type 'FromDTOImgs' is missing the following properties from type 'HomeModel': SportBikes, StreetBikes, AdventureBikes, ScooterBikes*

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: You put a lot of effort in creating the question and putting all the information in there. Yet, the most important part is missing: which error do you get in Angular? Can you check browser DevTools to analyze the result of the request? What is the status code that the server sends?

Comment: @Markus Thank you for mentioning my mistake. I haven't been quite sure about the way that I've used the forEach method in onHomeBikesImgsResponse method in app.componet.ts

Comment: @Markus Swagger displays status 200. DevTools displays status 404

Comment: @Random Sorry for the mistake. I'd appreciate it if you consider the edited version of the code, please

Comment: @Markus I'd appreciate it if you consider the edited version of the code, please

Comment: @Navid: 404 (NotFound) means that the URL that Angular used cannot be mapped to a controller action of the ASP.NET Core API. So you need to check if the URL that Angular uses is correct. As for the "not assignable" error: the method `onHomeBikesImgsResponse` expects a parameter of type `HomeModel[]`, but the service delivers `BikesImg[]`. Most likely, this is due to past and copy. I think you can use `BikesImg[]` as the parameter type of `onHomeBikesImgsResponse`.

Comment: @Markus: Thank you for the solution indeed. The error is gone now.

Comment: @Navid Good to hear that it worked. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You describe two separate problems:

The status code 404 (NotFound) means that the URL that Angular used cannot be mapped to a controller action of the ASP.NET Core API. So you need to check if the URL that Angular uses is correct.

As for the "not assignable" error: the method `onHomeBikesImgsResponse` expects a parameter of type `HomeModel[]`, but the service delivers `BikesImg[]`. Most likely, this is due to paste and copy. I think you can use `BikesImg[]` as the parameter type of `onHomeBikesImgsResponse`.